# endianness using struct.pack struct.unpack

Tags: python, endianness

I'm trying to read some binary datafiles.  The datafiles have a "sentinal" integer written in them which is always -1.  I thought that I could use this to check if the machine which wrote the data was big-endian or little-endian, but upon some experimentation it seems this isn't the case.  Specifically:

```
import struct
data=struct.pack('<i',-1)
print (struct.unpack('<i',data))  #(-1,)
print (struct.unpack('>i',data))  #(-1,) ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The representation of -1 is the same in big and liddle endian (and two's complement), i.e. (assuming 32 bit)

```
ffffffff # big endian
ffffffff # little endian
```

Check with a value such as `0x01020304`, or, if you want to add additional checks, `0x0d0aff00` (`0d0a` is the Windows [EOL CRLF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), `ff` will break over 8bit-opaque channels, and `00` will break null-terminated strings).

Comment: Right...didn't think of that.  *sigh*  I guess it's time to petition the people creating the datafiles to change that -1 to some other integer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The value -1 is represented as 0XFFFFFFFF in binary (two's compliment). It will look the same in regardless of endian-ness.